# How do I prevent vim from tab-completing .class files?

Tags: vim

When I use `:e` in vim, it will tab-complete `.class` files before the `.java` files. As I never want to edit `.class` files, how do I prevent vim from showing `.class` files in the tab-completion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [suffixes option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#suffixes) in your vimrc to de-prioritize or ignore files with .class extensions.

Here's a simple example:

```
" suffixes to put to the end of the list when completing file names
set suffixes=.bak,~,.o,.h,.info,.swp,.class
```

Comment: I ended up using `wildignore`, but your answer led me there. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Use the following in your vimrc file:

```
set wildignore=*.class
```

You can comma delimit it to add more than one pattern

```
set wildignore=*.class,*.rbc
```

See [the wildignore documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'wildignore') for more details (though there's not much more to add)